# Is there a way for making an Forkjoin iterative?

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a single Observable from multiple http requests, it seems Forkjoin is the answer, but they number of calls depends on the data requested (for example, you can ask data from a year or from a week).

So this is the current code:

```
        Observable.forkJoin(
            //Now the requests fires twice, but its 
            //possible this will be fired a 100+ times
            this.markersHistoryService.fetch(macAddress, 1527853624000, 1528199224000),
            this.markersHistoryService.fetch(macAddress, 1528199224000, 1528631224000)
        ).subscribe((history: MarkerData[], MarkerData[]): void => {
            let firstResult:MarkerData = history[0];
            const secondResult:MarkerData = history[1];
            firstResult = firstResult.concat(secondResult)
            subscribe.next([...firstResult]);
            subscribe.complete();
        });
```

It works, but it isnt dynamic. So  I am thinking it should be some kind of forloop, where the parameters will be generated into EPOCH times, and width these parameters the requests should be made.

Second iteration:

```
        const daysBetween = function (date1, date2) {
            const one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            let difference_ms = date2 - date1;
            return Math.round(difference_ms / one_day);
        };
        let observablesArr = [];
        for (let i:number = 0; i < daysBetween(timeStart, timeEnd); i++) {
            observablesArr.push(this.markersHistoryService.fetch(macAddress, 1516523557000, 1528199224000))
        }
        Observable.forkJoin(observablesArr).subscribe((history: MarkerData[]): void => {
                subscribe.next([...history]);
                subscribe.complete();
            });
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Greetings, Bram

Comment: You might want to look into the `switchAll` operator. You can emit observables into it and it will always emit the results of the most recent observable

Comment: I will look into this. It sounds like a viable option indeed. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array and push the request to it and then send the req through `forkJoin`

```
let observablesArr = []

yourArr.forEach((item) => {
  observablesArr.push(item) // push you requests
})

Observable.forkJoin(observablesArr  ). sunscribe(.....
```

Comment: You are iterating over an array and pushing its items into another array without doing anything else, seems kinda pointless

Comment: because OP didn't provide more details like how to generate the array dynamically. This is just an example. OP has to generate the array and need to follow something similar to this.

Comment: I've added a second iteration, the numbers will be dynamicly in the future but the current output is a gaint array of arrays, the Subscribe method should fix this right?

Answer (score 0):

Push all your request into an array. The final array of requests/Observable should look like below  :

```js
const serviceArray = [ 
                      this.markersHistoryService.fetch(macAddress, 1527853624000, 1528199224000),
                      this.markersHistoryService.fetch(macAddress, 1528199224000, 1528631224000)
                      ];   // can be 1000+ items.
                      
// now do  following  : 

 Observable.forkJoin(
           serviceArray
        ).subscribe((resultArray): void => {
             // resultArray[0] -  will contain 1st item result
             // resultArray[1] -  will contain 2nd item result
            subscribe.next([...firstResult]);
            subscribe.complete();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its similiar to Sachila's one, which leaves me with the question that it gives me a array of arrays, where I just want a single one.

Comment: @B.Wesselink are you talking about result array ?

Comment: yes I am! The output that I want should be a combined array of objects, I aint sure of my original question made that clear.